# Entries in Nested Dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

Given a nested Dictionary:

```
myDict = { 'through': { 1: 18,
                        2: 27,
                        3:  2,
                        4: 15,
                        5: 63
                        },
           'one':     { 1: 27,
                        2: 15,
                        3: 24,
                        4:  9,
                        5: 32
                        },
           'clock':   { 1:  2,
                        2:  5,
                        3:  9,
                        4:  6,
                        5: 15
                        }
           }
```

The outer key is a word, the inner keys are the files that that word contains and the values are the number of times said word appears in that file.

**How would I use the file numbers to work out the total number of text files that were present?**

i.e. **Is there a way of extracting the number of key / value pairs in the inner dictionary?**

i.e. `numOfFiles = 5`

Because there are 5 files here, but say I had hundreds and they were read into this dictionary automatically, so I had to work it out?

Comment: can show us expected output???

Comment: edited to include :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`len` function calculate the length:

```
>>>len(myDict['through'])
5
```

if you want word and how many files contains it: you can use dictionary comprehension

```
>>>{ x:len(y) for x,y in myDict.items() }
{'one': 5, 'through': 5, 'clock': 5}
```

you asked for key/value pair:

```
 >>> [ y.items() for x,y in myDict.items() ]
[[(1, 2), (2, 5), (3, 9), (4, 6), (5, 15)], [(1, 18), (2, 27), (3, 2), (4, 15), (5, 63)], [(1, 27), (2, 15), (3, 24), (4, 9), (5, 32)]]
```

`items`gives tuple of key/value pair for inner dictionary

if word is not present infile, then it will check for greater than 0:

```
>>> myDict
{'clock': {1: 2, 2: 5, 3: 9, 4: 6, 5: 15}, 'through': {1: 18, 2: 27, 3: 2, 4: 15, 5: 63}, 'one': {1: 27, 2: 15, 3: 0, 4: 9, 5: 32}}
>>>{ x:len(filter(lambda x:x if x > 0 else False,y.values())) for x,y in myDict.items() }
{'one': 4, 'through': 5, 'clock': 5}
```

here one is not present in file 3

Comment: I hope this might help you to get your desired output

Comment: So this just creates an ordinary dictionary? Also, would this work if a word was not in a file. So say 'clock' was not in file 3 and had a value of 0 instead of 24, would it be able to produce: {'one':5, 'through':5, 'clock':4} ?

Comment: clock in file 3 has 9 not 24

Comment: instead of using a lambda, you could use `bool`

Comment: `{ x:len(filter(bool, y.values())) for x,y in myDict.items() }`

Comment: So bool has the same functionality as checking whether x > 0?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the total number of files that contains that word, use `len`

`len(myDict['through'])`

If you need the number of the total existent files:

`max([len(x) for x in myDict.values()])`

Comment: Great thank you. What if the dictionary had hundred of outer keys and I didn't know whether a certain word would be present?

Comment: Use the second option